# Parsing unusual XML with Linq

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-xml, webclient

I get a peculiar response back from a webservice:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetLemonadeResponse xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/">
      <GetLemonadeResult>&lt;Response&gt;&lt;Status&gt;Error&lt;/Status&gt;&lt;Message&gt;Could not find the Lemonade for this State/Lemon&lt;/Message&gt;&lt;FileNumber /&gt;&lt;/Response&gt;</GetLemonadeResult>
    </GetLemonadeResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

2 questions:

1) I am not sure why the content of GetLemonadeResult has deviant content (like "& l t ;").

I migrate the bytes to string this way:

```
WebClientEx client = new WebClientEx();
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] result = client.UploadData(_baseUri.ToString(), data);
client.Encoding.GetBytes(xml));
string resultString = client.Encoding.GetString(result);
```

(WebClientEx derives from WebClient with an extra Timeout property).

I am thinking if I picked the wrong encoding the outer part of the response would be mangled the same way.

Does the web service have an error?

2) Why is it that when I try to grab "GetLemonadeResult" using Linq to XML it can't pull anything?

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(response); // returns the XML posted above
var responseAsXML = xdoc.Descendants("GetLemonadeResult"); // gets nothing
```

I wouldn't have guessed I'd need a namespace to catch the descendants since the XML GetLemonadeResult tag doesn't have a prepending "tag:".

Comment: I dont see "GetClosingProtectionLetterResult" in your example response?

Comment: `GetClosingProtectionLetterResult ` doesn't exist in the sample XML you provided. Please update your question with an XML that does contain it.

Comment: @cgtian: so much for disguising what industry I'm coming from! Apologies ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Some chars which can invalidate the xml like <,> etc. are escaped

**2)** You forget to include namespaces in your code

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(response);
XNamespace soap = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
XNamespace ns = "http://microsoft.com/webservices/";
var responseAsXML = xdoc.Descendants(soap + "Body")
                        .Descendants(ns + "GetLemonadeResult")
                        .First().Value;
```

`responseAsXML` would be

```
<Response>
<Status>Error</Status>
<Message>Could not find the Lemonade for this State/Lemon
</Message><FileNumber />
</Response>
```

**EDIT**

This is the soap/xml I used to test

```
string response = @"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
                        <soap:Body>
                        <GetLemonadeResponse xmlns=""http://microsoft.com/webservices/"">
                            <GetLemonadeResult>&lt;Response&gt;&lt;Status&gt;Error&lt;/Status&gt;&lt;Message&gt;Could not find the Lemonade for this State/Lemon&lt;/Message&gt;&lt;FileNumber /&gt;&lt;/Response&gt;</GetLemonadeResult>
                        </GetLemonadeResponse>
                        </soap:Body>
                    </soap:Envelope>";
```

Comment: @micahhoover I used the soap/xml in your question and it returns the xml I posted. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I was making a foolish error on my end. The envelope does not need to be explicitly "descended".